# POST 404 not found when sending email through contact form using Nodemailer and OAuth2 in production heroku hosted

Tags: reactjs, post, oauth, fetch, nodemailer

I am trying to set up a contact form which Utilizes Nodemailer and OAuth2 build on React framework.  In Development everything works perfectly, after deploying to Heroku and attempting to submit a POST request through the contact form I get a POST 404 error in my fetch request.  Ive scoured the net and haven't found a solution which has been able to resolve this issue.

SERVER CODE:

```
const express = require("express");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const app = express();
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
const cors = require("cors");
require('dotenv').config()

const PASSWORD = process.env.password;
const EMAIL = process.env.email;
const TOKEN = process.env.OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN;
const SECRET = process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET;
const CLIENT = process.env.OAUTH_CLIENTID;

const oauthClient = new OAuth2(
    CLIENT,
    SECRET,

    "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground"
)

oauthClient.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: TOKEN
});

const accessToken = oauthClient.getAccessToken()

// middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`)
});

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
        type: "OAuth2",
        user: EMAIL,
        pass: PASSWORD,
        clientId: CLIENT,
        clientSecret: SECRET,
        refreshToken: TOKEN,
        accessToken: accessToken
    },
 });

 transporter.verify((err, success) => {
    err
        ? console.log(err)
        : console.log(`=== Server is ready to take messages: ${success} ===`);
 });

 app.post("/send", function (req, res) {
    let mailOptions = {
        from: `${req.body.mailerState.email}`,
        to: EMAIL,
        subject: `${req.body.mailerState.subject} from ${req.body.mailerState.name}`,
        text: `You received this email from ${req.body.mailerState.name} @ ${req.body.mailerState.email} They wrote: \n${req.body.mailerState.message}`,
    };
 
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error " + err, "data " + data);
            res.json({
                status: "fail"
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Email sent successfully");
            res.json({ status: "success" });
        }
    });
 });
```

FETCH REQ:

```
    const submitEmail = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log({ mailerState });
        const response = await fetch("https://<myapp>.herokuapp.com/send", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ mailerState }),
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(async (res) => {
                const resData = await res;
                console.log(resData);
                if (resData.status === "success") {
                    alert("Message sent");
                } else if (resData.status === "fail") {
                    alert("Message failed to send.")
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                setMailerState({
                    email: "",
                    name: "",
                    subject: "",
                    message: "",
                });
            });
    };
```

In development my fetch url is `http://localhost:3001/send`